# href does not want to get printed although I followed the path

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

I want to enter a link in a webpage. This is its location in the inspect element: 
[image]
 As You can see, to reach the link in the < body >, I have to pass through:

1) < div class = "container" >

2) < div id = "result content >

3) < div class="tabbable tabs-left" >

4) < ul class ="nav... >

There are many < li >, typically I want to collect the hrefs of the class visible phone. The code I have does not prints nothing. What am i doing wrong??

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://openie.allenai.org/search?arg1=&rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&corpora=')
array = page.search('//body/div[@id="result-content"]/div[@class="tabbable tabs-left"]/ul[@class="nav nav-tabs"]/li[@class="visible-phone"]/a').each do |x|
    puts x['href']
end
```

Comment: you did not include `< div class = "container" >` div

Comment: @LuthandoLoot I included it now and tested but it still does not work.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz try with much simpler xpath first : `//li[@class="visible-phone"]/a`

Comment: thanks @har07 ,how can i save only the first li href in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me, you also can try ;)

```
  array = page.search('//*[@class="visible-phone"]/a').each { |i|
    puts i['href']
  }
```

UPD:

```
 first_link_page = page.link_with(:href => array.first['href']).click
```

UPD2:

```
array = page.search('//*[@class="visible-phone"]/a')
first_link_page = page.link_with(:href => array.first['href']).click
```

Comment: It did work! But how can I access the first href? I tried the "click" but it gave me an error.

Comment: "undefined method 'click' for #<String:xxx> < NoMethodError > "

Comment: this is the peice of code `res = res.search('//li[@class="visible-phone"]/a')[0]['href'].click`

Comment: @Sarahcartenz see UPD

Comment: I think that ill just `get` the first href rather then just clicking it.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz add your code plz, cause it's must work, it work for me

Comment: @Sarahcartenz oh, I'm so sorry, check UPD2, it must work